# Why does virtual box vboxheadless process using Vagrant use 100% of my cpu?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

So I'm using a couple vagrant boxes and when i have them up, "sometimes/randomly" it starts to take up 100% cpu on my OS X machine and i have no idea whats causing it. I can ssh into the vmachine and check the load and it's at 0 sot its not something thats running in the box.

The only way I can fix this is if i suspend it and resume it, then it goes away until randomly it starts to happen again. Sometimes hours later, sometimes days later.

The only thing I can think of is it might be because i'm using nfs mounts within my virtual machine to access my projects, but i'm not sure yet.  Any ideas?

Comment: Old question, but still had this issue with latest Vagrant/VBox. Turns out the was a routing loop because I wasn't accesing the guest services via the private IP. See https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14137#comment:16

Comment: I finally got around to checking this. Nope, i've always been using the private ip and not my local ip.  So its something else thats causing this on my end.

Comment: One days I was watching youtube videos with safari and only one tab open, all my other apps is closed and I just saw the fan speed got higher and in the activity monitor That vboxheadless takes up to !60% cpu.

Answer (score 26):

EngineerCoder's answer only applies if you're using CoreOS.

I've run into problems if the VirtualBox Extensions pack version differs from the version of VirtualBox. Also, install the Vagrant VirtualBox guest plugin:

`vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest`

And make sure to update the plugin when you update Virtualbox and the extension pack:

`vagrant plugin update vagrant-vbguest`

Comment: ok so i tried this and still no luck.  :(  I'm going to try disabling nfs and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Did it help, @David?

Answer (score 17):

For **Vagrant with CoreOS only** please do the following:

- Set `$enable_serial_logging=false` in `config.rb`
- `vagrant destroy`
- `vagrant up`
- Observe three VBoxHeadless processes under 3% CPU

[This PR](https://github.com/coreos/coreos-vagrant/pull/85) is a working source of this info.

For **Vagrang with any vm** you can also try disabling nested paging.

See ["Fix High Guest CPU Utilization in VirtualBox by disabling Nested Paging" article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150326104402/http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2010/09/22/fix-high-guest-cpu-utilization-in-virtualbox-by-disabling-nested-paging.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Where is this `config.rb` supposed to be?

Comment: vagrant/plugins/providers/virtualbox/config.rb

Answer (score 6):

#### Step 1: keep guest additions up to date

Make sure you have vbguest plugin that will keep your guest additions up to date:

```
vagrant plugin update vagrant-vbguest
```

If it wasn't installed already, you can install it with:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest
```

#### Step 2: disable sound

In VirtualBox window:

- Click on the machine you are using
- Click settings
- Go to: Audio Tab
- Uncheck both "Enable Audio Output" and "Enable Audio Input"

#### Step 3: reduce general CPU consumption

(Optional) Note: this step will decrease your VM maximum performance!

You may reduce the general CPU consumption:

- Click on the Machine --> Settings --> System --> Processor
- Reduce the Execution Cap. This limits the % of the host CPU, that the guest CPU can use. (Default, is 100% - no limit).

Comment: That's unbelievable! All the other answers didn't help, but simply disabling the Audio devices **INSTANTLY SOLVED the problem for me!!**  – Why is this happening? Why didn't it happen for the last months (when I actually updated Virtualbox) but just in the last few days? Is it a Virtualbox bug, a loop of any kind? And why disabling the audio solves it? It's crazy to have an issue on a device that my machine is not even relying on  – In any case, thank you, you put an end to hours of trying to figure out what was happening and let me come back to actual productive work 

Comment: Additional question mark: re-enabling Audio Input & Output will **not** instantly provoke the CPU issue on the running box. Didn't try to reload, tho.

Comment: [Here an example or solved problem from Virtualbox forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=89896&sid=ce1a6b075ed3d6f06a2bec0dece11411&start=15). By the way, for me it was sufficient to just uncheck the *"Enable Audio Input"*; output can stay enabled in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I have [disabled System Integrity Protection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-macos-os-x) in order to be able to use `iosnoop` to diagnose high `ioctl` activity, which seems to cause 100% CPU usage.

The problem disappeared. So I believe it has something to do with SIP.