# High CPU Usage VirtualBox & Vagrant | VboxHeadless

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, cpu

Hello guys im struggle with my Vagrant and VirtualBox if im doing vagrant up my CPU usage for VboxHeadless is going up to 200% and more im already tryed all the solutions on stack and another sites im on MacOs 16gb i7 and SSD so i have enough performance also the setting in vagrant files are fine. anybody an Idea or Solution for this common bug?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does virtual box vboxheadless process using Vagrant use 100% of my cpu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293238/why-does-virtual-box-vboxheadless-process-using-vagrant-use-100-of-my-cpu)