# Where do I put the $enable_serial_logging flag in vagrant?

Tags: logging, vagrant, virtual-machine, cpu, homestead

The vm keeps overclocking my processor. I read that I can add the `$enable_serial_logging = false` flag to prevent this problem but which file do I put it in and where?

[image: standard Vagrant file structure]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does virtual box vboxheadless process using Vagrant use 100% of my cpu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293238/why-does-virtual-box-vboxheadless-process-using-vagrant-use-100-of-my-cpu)

Answer (score 1):

Within config.rb you can set `$enable_serial_logging=false`

```
# Log the serial consoles of CoreOS VMs to log/
# Enable by setting value to true, disable with false
# WARNING: Serial logging is known to result in extremely high CPU usage with
# VirtualBox, so should only be used in debugging situations
$enable_serial_logging=false
```

See here: https://gist.github.com/dalekurt/5c0dbaf26b96f4504011#file-config-rb-L49